# How to map boolean in hibernate hbm file

Tags: java, hibernate

In my database, i have column like

```
"ISDEFAULTPAYMENTFORCURRENCY" CHAR(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
CHECK (ISDEFAULTPAYMENTFORCURRENCY IN ('N','Y')) ENABLE,
```

In my bean, i have

```
    private Boolean isDefaultPaymentForCurrency;
```

my question, how can i map this `isDefaultPaymentForCurrency` in hibernate hbm file?

```
<property name="isDefaultPaymentForCurrency" type="???" column="ISDEFAULTPAYMENTFORCURRENCY" not-null="true"/>
```

Comment: your bean should be , `Boolean`, type="java.lang.Boolean" or `type="yes_no"` i don't remember

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<property name="isDefaultPaymentForCurrency"  type="yes_no" column="ISDEFAULTPAYMENTFORCURRENCY" not-null="true"/>
```

And to use hql you can set this property in `hibernate.cfg`

```
<property name="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 'Y', false 'N'</property>
```

Comment: if I do not want to modify hibernate.cfg file then can i have boolean type in Oracle with true or false value?

Comment: I think if you put `yes_no` when you save to your db if you put `setIsDefaultPaymentForCurrency(Boolean.TRUE)` will be save `Y`

Comment: @Rachel That's apply for using hql... it's like instead of using Y or N you use true or false.

Comment: @Rachel ok , keep coding :D

Comment: I have ran into other related issues and so am yet to test it out but am accepting the answer as I think it would resolve my issue, will update results once things work as expected for me with change mentioned !!!

Comment: how to set default value when using this approach?

Answer (score 3):

Type mappings from Java primitives or wrapper classes to appropriate (vendor-specific) SQL
column types. `boolean`, `yes_no`, and `true_false` are all alternative encodings for a Java boolean or `java.lang.Boolean`.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/mapping-types.html

Answer (score 2):

I refer [the link, Hibernate Mapping Types](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_types.htm), and use `boolean` finally.

A `hbm.xml` example.

```
    <property name="scheduable" type="boolean" >
        <column name="SCHEDUABLE" not-null="true" default="false" />
    </property>
```

---

[image: The mapping types image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the following type: `org.hibernate.type.YesNoType`. The following [reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html) may be used for this (in particular section 6.1.1.3). Registered as `yes_no`